# Resize of the Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to change the Viewer size with bootstrap (using col to parent div) but the model doesn't stand in the middle of the Viewer. I used event `Autodesk.Viewing.VIEWER_RESIZE_EVENT` and `viewer.resize()` but it doesn't trigger. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to look for the container changing size and not the viewer.

`viewer.resize()` Will trigger the event `Autodesk.Viewing.VIEWER_RESIZE_EVENT` - but what you would need instead is an event listener on the div around or window, like

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
   viewer.resize();
});
```